# How to check if user is in many to many model django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i am trying to do permission for user where i defined my model like this

```
class UserInstances(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True,unique=False)
   instance_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
   instance_size = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
   instance_objects = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
   instance_map = models.TextField()
   instance_permission = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='instance_permission')

   def __str__(self):
       return f"{self.instance_name} instance for {self.user}"
```

API code

```
    user = Token.objects.get(key=request.auth)
    if UserInstances.objects.get(id=2).instance_permission.exists(user) :// for demonstration
         print("access granted")
```

Can you tell me how to check if user exist or not in many to many field object

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`.values_list('{your field}', flat=True)`

and then use

`in` python methode

or you can append users id in a list and then use
`in` python methode like this:

```
users = UserInstances.objects.get(id=2).instance_permission.all()
usres_list_id = []
for user in users:
    usres_list_id.append(user.id)
if user_instance.id in users_id_list:
    #do somethong
```

Answer (score 0):

Many-to-many relationships can be queried using lookups across relationships, please refer to the Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Long story short, you can filter the `UserInstances` model and query for the users in `instance_permission`, i.e. using `instance_permission__in`.